# Thumbnails stacked over each other in Nivo slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Nivo slider & the thumbnails are stacked over each other but the question is totally related to CSS.

The demo page is at http://jsbin.com/ebomu4 and I can't seem to pull them off.

Comment: what is the csss of your .nivo-controlNav a

Comment: @kjy112 No matter what I put in, I can't get it to work.

Comment: first of all your thumb are abit too big to fit all on one line because the width of the slider is set `618px` and 4 x 150 plus the paddings and margins pushes the thumbs to two rows, but i'll post what i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i modified and basically took out what you had previously.  The demo can be viewed here [jsfiddle nivo-slider](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/HZBem/):

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;  //i set the navigation thumb all the way to the left because the size of your thumb + padding + margin was making it overflow to new rows
    bottom:-350px; //setting the navControl position relative to the slide
}

//here is what i added
 .nivo-controlNav a {
    display:inline;
}

.nivo-controlNav img {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.nivo-controlNav a.active img {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

i set the navigation thumb all the way to the left because the size of your thumb + padding + margin was making it overflow to new rows. i also set the navControl position relative to the slide by setting the `bottom:-350px;`  I added the `.nivo-controlNav`'s `a` `img` and active state of img to make it show up, but due to the width of your slider it overflow to line 2.  hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that is totally what I wanted, they are not stacked over each other any more. :)